# How to Modify a Texas instruments sensor tag android application code which is already functional?

Tags: android, texas-instruments

I'm totally new to programming. I need to modify an Open source Sensor tag app code which I found on google play store. (Type Sensor tag TI in Google Play store)

In the app, If I press the push button carbon on the sensor tag, instead of an image that shows a key getting pressed, I need a message to be displayed.

Information regarding Sensor Tag : Type sensor tag wiki in google search

Can anyone please help me modifying this code ( https://github.com/geobio/sensortag ), because I'm totally new to coding and need to complete this as soon as possible. I used eclipse to Import the source from github.

Answer (score 3):

while googling I can across this question. I thought I'd keep it updated in case some one else comes across this (or I forget how I did it when I get time to come back on this project). I am new to sensor tag iot thingies too!

Firstly, I have cloned a copy of the repo from https://git.ti.com/sensortag-android , and also updated it to use android lollipop (5.1).

I have some new SensortTags and I found that the new tags are filtered out (I got my tags in March 2015) so to get my to work I have added CC2650 SensorTag to the device_filter in the strings.xml resources file. this way the *mLeScanCallback* in the MainActivity.java will pick up the sensor.

```
<string-array name="device_filter">
  <item>SensorTag</item>
  <item>SensorTag2</item>
  <!-- The new tags -->
  <item>CC2650 SensorTag</item>
</string-array>
```

That should give you a list of your tags in the BLE Device List.

The next step I am still try to get working was to get all the sensors talking. I have amended the onCreate method in the DeviceActivity.java to treat the new tags as a sensorTag2.

```
        // Determine type of SensorTagGatt
        String deviceName = mBluetoothDevice.getName();
        mIsSensorTag2 = deviceName.equals("CC2650 SensorTag");
```

This should list a few sensors in your sensors list view. You may need to enable the sensors you want to display, defined in the preferences.xml and preferences2.xml. I am still trying to get all the sensors reading and displaying properly, so once that is done, I may write a post on it and how I got it all working.